How can I make this menu permanently expanded? (Is this caused by VSCode or Ubuntu?)
Background
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (which includes Gnome 46).
I'm also running the latest version of VSCode:

Version: 1.95.2
Commit: e8653663e8840adaf45af01eab5c627a5af81807
Date:2024-11-07T11:07:22.054Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0 OS:
Linux x64 6.8.0-48-generic

Context Menu Not Expanded
Recently, I started noticing that the the context menu always has to be expanded to get to commonly used items (copy / paste ,etc)
In this image you can see that the entire menu does not show up.
Red Arrow: The red arrow shows that the copy menu item isn't entirely shown
Blue Arrow: The blue arrow points at a "expander" arrow which forces the user to slide down and over to see the rest of the menu items.

Questions

Is there any way to get back to the fully expanded context menu?  (So I don't have to float over it to make it display.)

What is causing this?  Is it Ubuntu 24.04? or is it VSCode?


